# What is the difference between closing an iOS app and force quitting/killing an app?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, silentpush

I don't understand the difference between closing an app and killing it from the user point if view.

As far as I know if I want to **close** an app I will proceed like explained here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201330

But if I want to kill the app, how me, as a user, can do this? I know for android if you search in settings for that app there is a button called force stop.

I ask this because I want to use silent notifications and don't know what they mean here:
*If something force quits or kills the app, the system discards the held notification.* It's taken from this page:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

Comment: what's explained in that link is closing the app, same as killing it.

Comment: so there is no difference between closing and killing other than semantics of the words

Comment: yes. There are only two states, either app lives in background or you kill it by swiping up, from that point, it will not be in background.